# Go get parent directory

Tags: go, path, directory, filepath

I've some command line program which I need to read files from parent folder, I mean

```
-parentDir
 -- myproject
 --- cmd
 ----main.go 

 --otherdir
  -file.json
```

As you can see `otherdir` is like sibling to `myproject` and I need from my `main.go` read the `file.json`

what I've tried is like following

```
func visit(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
  fmt.Printf("Visited: %s\n", path)
  return nil
} 


func main() {
  flag.Parse()
  root := flag.Arg(0)
  err := filepath.Walk(root, visit)
  fmt.Printf("filepath.Walk() returned %v\n", err)
}
```

I've also try to provide args(-1) which doesnt help...
Any idea how from `command line` program I can read some files that on level up from my executable ?

I've also tried with

```
import "github.com/mitchellh/go-homedir"


func Path(path string) (error, string) {
    home, err := homedir.Dir()
   }
```

this give the root directory which doesnt help either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the binary is, it matters what the working directory is (the directory you're in when you execute the program). All relative paths will be relative to the current working directory. So, if you're executing from `myproject`, you'd use something like `../` as the root path to `Walk`.

That said, I would **highly recommend** you make the path configurable, rather than assuming the binary will always be executed from some particular location within the source tree.

Comment: thanks but ..`otherdir` is constant in your solution, and it actually can be any name and I cannot predict it. something that I know that I should find the file.json in the `otherdirN` which in the same level of the `myproj`

Comment: That's fine, just use `Walk` with the root at e.g. `../`. However... what if there are json files in multiple sibling directories? Again, this seems like it should be solved with a config parameter to specify the exact path to be used, rather than trying to walk a directory structure based on current working directory. Doing it as you've described will lead to more problems in the future.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the right `walk` solution ?

Comment: It's *exactly the same code you have* with a different root, as explained.